# Microeconomics of GDP

Tags: gdp, general-equilibrium

Macroeconomists tend to study GDP in terms of macro variables.

Microeconomists study general equilibrium (among other thinga of course).

Is there theory about the relation between general equilibrium and GDP? Where should I look for this?

Comment: Macroeconomics nowadays tend to require [microfoundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfoundations). As a result, general equilibrium are more of a topic for macro than micro analysis. The [dynamic stochastic general equilibrium (DSGE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_stochastic_general_equilibrium) model and its variants underlie much of macroeconomic analysis nowadays.

Comment: @HerrK. You might consider converting your comment to an answer. I think you're comment pretty much sums it all up.

Answer (score 1):

Macroeconomics nowadays tend to require [microfoundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfoundations). As a result, general equilibrium are more of a topic for macro than micro analysis. The [dynamic stochastic general equilibrium (DSGE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_stochastic_general_equilibrium) model and its variants underlie much of macroeconomic analysis nowadays.

Standard texts:

- [Stokey and Lucas (1989) *Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674750969)
- [Ljungqvist and Sargent (2004) *Recursive Macroeconomic Theory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026212274X)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be interested in the identification of [Balanced Growth Path (BGP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced-growth_equilibrium) . It one of the topics covered in advanced macroeconomics.

David Romer gives it a good treatment in his book advanced macroeconomics.